# Add css class to a div based on active cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to set cookies on particular pages.

Can someone show me how to add a css class to an id (such as add class .red to #mouse if cookie = "socks" is true)

i.e.: 
If the the current session has a cookie named socks active, find `<div id="mouse">` and make it `<div id="mouse" class="socks">`

I'm using Wordpress for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the [docs](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#usage) is very clear:

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('name'); // => "value" 
$.cookie('nothing'); // => undefined
```

In short, it should be something like this:

```
if ($.cookie('socks')) {
    $('#mouse').addClass('red')
}
```